# In R, need to find best combination of 8 columns, only being able to select one value from each row

Tags: r, optimization

In R, I'm attempting to find the best combination of 8 different columns of values but with the caveat of only being able to select one value from each row. It sounds relatively simple, but I'm trying to avoid a nasty looping scenario to evaluate all possible options, so I'm hopeful there is a function available that could make this a possibility.  There are scenarios where I will need to run this on datasets with over 2000 rows, so efficiency is really important.

Here is an example:

[image: example dataset and highlighted desired result]

I've been racking my brain and searching forever, but every scenario and solution I'm able to find can maximize series of columns but cant handle the condition of only allowing a single value per row. Are there any functions where this is possible?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, ccott235! In addition to giving unambiguous, usable data, can you also provide some more details on your "best column" heuristic? It's not "max", so it isn't clear what you mean.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong ccott, but by "the best combination" you mean that you want the 8 number whose sum is the greatest, right? Of course, given the condition that one cannot belong to the same column or row of another number...

Comment: Same, can you explain a bit more what you do call best combination ?

Comment: I think I understand. You are asking for an "optimal solution", specifically *"maximize the sum given exactly one number per column"*. I don't see any pattern in the numbers, which makes this difficult. Typically there needs to be some derivative or gradient function (and often a notion of "convexity"), a method used to inform the branch-and-bound (or similar) method of finding good candidates. Lacking this, the pure optimal approach suggests an exhaustive approach, which may not work with ~2000 rows.

Comment: Do you know that a practical solution for this problem exists? You may need to accept a heuristic (i.e., known compromise) by limiting the candidate values used in an exhaustive approach.

Comment: The solution to this is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)? If so, there are R packages implementing it, package clue function [solve_LSAP](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clue/versions/0.3-57/topics/solve_LSAP) or [RcppHungarian](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppHungarian/vignettes/Introduction-to-RcppHungarian.html).

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I think you are right. After reading a little bit more about this problem is an assignment problem, and the Hungarian algorithm is a good solution. The code placed below is basically me poorly reinventing this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I will take a risk here, and assume that I interpreted you right. That you seek the group of 8 numbers in that table that have the maximum sum. Given, of course that they do not share a column or a row.

There is no easy answer to this question. I am not a computer scientist, but I believe this is what is called an NP-hard problem. So efficiency will always be a problem. Fortunately, in practical terms, I think you can get an answer for a 2000+ table in a matter of seconds, as long as the number of columns remains small.

The algorithm I tried to use to win this problem is essentially a depth-first search that takes advantage of existing function in R that makes it faster. You can think of your problem as jumping from column to column, each time selecting the highest value with a twist. Every time you select a value, all cells in that row are turned to zero. So in essence, when you get to the last column, there will only be one value to choose.

However, due to this nature of excluding rows, your results will be different depending on the order you choose to visit the columns (let's call that a path). Thus, you have to test all paths.

So our code must be something of the sort:

1- Enumerate all paths (all permutations of column numbers);

2- For each path, "walk" it taking the maximum value of each column and transforming to 0 the values in its row. Store the values;

3- For each set of values, calculate its sum and select based on that.

Below is the code I have used to do it:

```
library(combinat) # loads permn function, that enumerates  all the permutations

#Create fake data
data = sample(1:25)
data = matrix(data,5,5)

# Walking function
walker = function(path,data) {

    bestn = numeric(length(path)) # Placeholder for the max value of each column
    usedrows = numeric(length(path)) #Placeholder for the row of each max value
    data.reduced=data  # copies data to a new object
    for(a in 1:length(path)) { # iterate through columns
        bestn[a] = max(data.reduced[,path[a]]) #find the maximum value
        usedrows[a] = which.max(data.reduced[,path[a]]) # find maximum value's row
        data.reduced[usedrows,]=0 # set all values in that row to 0
        data.reduced[,path[a]]=0 # set current column to 0.

    }
    return(bestn)
}

# Create all permutations and use functions in it, get their sum, and choose based on that
paths = permn(1:5)
values = lapply(paths,walker,data)
values.sum = sapply(values,sum)
values[[ which.max(values.sum)]]
```

The code can handle a matrix of 2000 x 5 in less than a second in a laptop. I just did not added it here, because the more rows, the more independent the results become from the path taken. And it is less easy to see its progress with large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved simply as a binary integer optimization problem.  Here using the ROI and ompr optimization packages.  ompr is a formulation manager that calls ROI functions for optimization and processing.  Here is an example:

```
require(ROI)
require(ROI.plugin.glpk)
require(ompr)
require(ompr.roi)

set.seed(7)
n <- runif(77, 80, 120)
n <- c(n, rep(0, 179))
n <- sample(n)
m <- matrix(n, ncol = 8)
nrows <- nrow(m)
ncols <- ncol(m)

model <- MIPModel() %>% 
      add_variable(x[i, j], i=1:nrows, j=1:ncols, type='binary', lb=0) %>%
      set_objective(sum_expr(colwise(m[i, j]) * x[i, j], i=1:nrows, j=1:ncols), 'max') %>%
      add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i=1:nrows) <= 1, j=1:ncols) %>%
      add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j=1:ncols) <= 1, i=1:nrows)

result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))
<SOLVER MSG>  ----
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.47
40 rows, 256 columns, 512 non-zeros
*     0: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*    20: obj =  9.321807877e+002  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.47
40 rows, 256 columns, 512 non-zeros
256 integer variables, all of which are binary
Integer optimization begins...
+    20: mip =     not found yet <=              +inf        (1; 0)
+    20: >>>>>  9.321807877e+002 <=  9.321807877e+002   0.0% (1; 0)
+    20: mip =  9.321807877e+002 <=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
<!SOLVER MSG> ----

solution <- get_solution(result, x[i, j])
solution <- subset(solution, value != 0)
solution
    variable  i j value
27         x 27 1     1
43         x 11 2     1
88         x 24 3     1
99         x  3 4     1
146        x 18 5     1
173        x 13 6     1
209        x 17 7     1
246        x 22 8     1
```

The first code chunk generates a 32X8 random matrix. The sample generates a 30% fill.  The constraints constrain each column and row to have <= 1 active variable.  You can use this code directly for any matrix of any dimension.